# EXT JS change row column

Tags: c#, extjs

I saw a couple of posts on how to change the color of a grid's row.
I tried to implement it like this:

Grid:

```
viewConfig: {
    stripeRows: false,
    getRowClass: function (rec, idx, rowPrms, ds) {
        return 'master-row'
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
master-row {background: red; color:Green}
```

the color Green is displaying fine, the backgorund isn't. I also tried with `background-color`, but no luck

What may I be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.master-row .x-grid-cell {background: red; color:Green}
```

You're adding a class so you'll need to use the css class selector (a point).
To color the cells u need to give the underlying grid cell a color and background color